# A power series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n= +\infty$ but $\lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n \ne \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation, power-series

> Let's consider the power series $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^n $ with radius of convergence $1$. Moreover let's suppose that : $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n= +\infty$. Then I would like to find a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ that respect the above condition and such that :
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 1, x < 1} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n \ne +\infty$$

First I've noticed that $a_n$ can't be a positive sequence, since if it was the case we would have for all $N$ :

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n \geq \sum_{n = 0}^N a_n$$

Hence we need some of the $a_n$ to be negative.
Moreover I need to use the assumption that the sum at $x = 1$ diverges, because if the sum at $x = 1$ converges then Abel's theorem says that the limit at $x \to 1$ and the sum of the power series at $x = 1$ are equal.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the inequality in your conclusion for positive $a_n$ be the other way round?

Comment: You are searching for an Abel summable sequence.

Comment: @maxmilgram No, though it takes a moment to realize that. You have $\lim_{x\to 1}\sum_{n=0}^N a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^Na_n$ (just polynomials). This means $\sum_{n=0}^N a_nx^n\ge\sum_{n=0}^Na_n - \epsilon$ for all $x>1-\delta$ for some $\delta$, corresponding to a chose $\epsilon > 0$. With all $a_n$ positive, we get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\ge\sum_{n=0}^Na_n - \epsilon$ for all $x>1-\delta$ for that $\delta$. From that follows what's in the post, because $\epsilon > 0$ can be chosen freely.

Comment: Writing $$\lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n \ne \infty$$ is a little strange. Why not ask: Does $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n =\infty?$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Such sequences don't exist. We prove this by contradiction:

Assume that $A_n := \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \rightarrow \infty$, $ f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^k$ is convergent in the unit disc and $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} f(x)$ exists. Removing finite many $a_i$ doesn't change the behaviour of $A_n$ and also not the existence of the limes for $x \uparrow 1$. Thus, we may assume that $A_n \ge 0$ for all $n \ge 1$. Now use Abel summation in the form
$$\label{1}\tag{1}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k = A_n x^n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} A_k x^k (1 - x).$$
Because
$$|A_n x^n| \le \sum_{j=1}^n |a_j| |x|^j$$
and the series is absolute convergent (as a power series) for $|x| < 1$, we see that $|A_n x^n|$ is bounded for fixed $|x| < 1$. Since $|A_n x^n| \le C(x)$, we get for all $|y| < |x|$ that $|A_n y^n| \le C(x) |y/x|^n \rightarrow 0$. Hence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } A_n y^n =0$ for all $|y| < |x|$. Since $x$ was arbitary, we get this statement for all $|y| <1$ (not necessarily uniform convergence).

Letting $n \rightarrow \infty$ in \eqref{1} gives for $|x| <1$ that
$$\label{2}\tag{2}f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k = (1-x) \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k x^k.$$
Since $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} f(x):=c$ exists (note that we can suppose that c>0, because we can w.l.o.g. increase $a_1$), we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_k x^k \sim \frac{1}{1-x}.$$
The [Hardy–Littlewood tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem) already implies that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (n+1-k) a_k =  \sum_{k=1}^n A_k \sim n.$$
But, we have
$$\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} A_k \ge \frac{1}{2} A_n \rightarrow \infty.$$
A contradiction!

> The problem changes rapidly, if we only require that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ is not convergent.

For example take $a_k = (-1)^k$: We have
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^k = \frac{1}{x+1}$$
and that $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} (x+1)^{-1} = 1/2$, but $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k$ is not convergent.

> As zhw shows in the second answer, we can also prove that $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} f(x) = \infty$.

Note for this that the identity in \eqref{2} implies, since $A_n >K$ for all $n \ge N$ that
$$f(x) \ge (1-x) K \sum_{k=N}^\infty x^k = K x^N$$
and thus $\liminf_{x \uparrow 1} f(x) \ge K$. Because $K>0$ is arbitary large, we get already $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} f(x) = \infty$.

Comment: How can you assume there is a finite a_i that a_i<0?

Comment: We don't know that $a_i <0$ only for finite many $i$, but we know that $A_n >0$ for all $n \ge N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, because $A_n \rightarrow \infty$. So removing all negative numbers of $a_1,\ldots,a_N$ gives $A_n \ge 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You are assuming $\lim_{\uparrow 1}f(x)$ exists?

Comment: Yes, my argument shows that the limes doesn't exist. In fact, your argument shows that the sequence tend to  $+\infty$. I have added also your argument to my answer. In fact, it is a more straight forward solution.

Comment: This doesn't prove that it is infinite, it just proves it can't be finite. This doesn't include the case where the limit just doesn't exist(finite or infinite) due to oscillation

Answer (score 4):

The following proof that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n = \infty$ seems simpler to me..

Lemma: Let $A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}|a_k|.$ Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_nx^n<\infty$ for $x\in (0,1).$

This follows from the fact that the radius of convergence is $1,$ which is the same as saying $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n} =1.$  This is a nice exercise. (A proof of the lemma is now in the comments.)

To prove the main result, let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_n;$ set $S_{-1}=0.$ Let $x\in (0,1).$ Then

$$\tag 1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(S_n-S_{n-1})x^n.$$

Now because $|S_n| \le A_n,$ the lemma shows we can write the last series as the difference of two convergent series, i.e. as

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S_nx^n - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S_{n-1}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S_nx^n - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S_{n}x^{n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S_nx^n(1-x).$$

Now let $M>0.$ Then there is $N$ such $S_n>M$ for $n>N.$ Write the last series as

$$(1-x)\left (\sum_{n=0}^{N}S_nx^n +\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}S_nx^n\right ) > (1-x)\left (\sum_{n=0}^{N}S_nx^n +Mx^{N+1}\frac{1}{1-x}\right ).$$

The $\liminf_{x\to 1^-}$ of the expression on the right equals $0 + M =M.$ We have thus shown the $\liminf_{x\to 1^-}$ of the left side of $(1)$ is $\ge M.$ Since $M$ was arbitrary, this $\liminf$ is $\infty.$ Thus the limit of left side of $(1)$ is $\infty$ as desired.

Comment: You mean $A_n = \sum_{ k = 0}^n \mid a_k \mid$, no ?

Comment: @Thinking Yes, thanks. Will correct.

Comment: You didn't completely correct the typo. I know that if we denote $K_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k$ then $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty K_n x^n$ converges since it comes from a Cauchy product. But I don't see why $\sum_{k = 0}^n A_kx^k$ converges, you don't know if the Cauchy test is going to work on the sequence $a_n$.

Comment: @Thinking I certainly corrected the typo. It seems you have another question. I'll be back.

Comment: ? So $A_n$ is just $(n+1)\mid a_n \mid$ ?

Comment: @Thinking  No, $A_n$ doesn't equal that. See my proof below.

Comment: Proof of the Lemma: Fix $x\in (0,1).$ Choose $\epsilon >0$ such that $x(1+\epsilon)<1.$ Because the radius of convergence is $1,$ we have $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n} =1.$ Thus $|a_n|\le (1+\epsilon)^n$ for large $n,$ say $n>N.$ Choose $C>1$ such that $|a_n|\le C, n\le N.$ Then $|a_n|\le C(1+\epsilon)^n$ for all $n.$ Thus $A_n \le Cn(1+\epsilon)^n$ for all $n.$ Therefore $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_nx^n \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} Cn[(1+\epsilon)x]^n.$ The last series converges since $(1+\epsilon)x<1.$

Comment: @zhw Thank you, but I am sorry to say that you are probably "blind", with the definition of your $A_n$ Thinking is right we have $A_n = (n+1) \mid a_n \mid$

Comment: You're right! I was suffering from author's blindness. Now corrected. (Apologies to @Thinking)

Answer (score 2):

What we **can** do is this similar example.

> A power series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ diverges, but $\lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n$ exists.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n = \frac{-1}{1+x},\quad -1< x < 1
\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\quad\text{diverges}
\\
\lim_{x \to 1^-}\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n = \frac{-1}{2}
$$

A noted in the other examples, Abel's theorem says we **cannot** do this in a power series with positive coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The above is the answer to your question,see if it is clear to you.

Comment: They already rejected (proved) this case is the question itself, the one where all terms are non-negative