# Does $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\neq\infty$ implies $-\infty<\liminf\sum_{n=0}^N a_n\le\limsup\sum_{n=0}^N a_n<+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, summation-method

**Notation**. This question deals with series of real terms $\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=1$: the following terminology is used.

- If $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_0^N a_n=\lim_{N\to\infty} s_N=\sum_0^\infty a_n=\pm\infty$ the series is *divergent*.
- If $-\infty<\lim_{N\to\infty} s_N=\sum_0^\infty a_n<+\infty$ the series is *convergent*.
- If $\nexists\lim_{N\to\infty} s_N=\sum_0^\infty a_n$ i.e. $\liminf_{N\to\infty} s_N\neq \limsup_{N\to\infty} s_N$ the series is *not convergent* or *oscillating*.

**The heart of the matter**. This question was inspired by [this one and related answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085628/a-power-series-sum-n-0-infty-a-nxn-such-that-sum-n-0-infty-a-n). Simply stated, the result proved there says that if $\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a real sequence such that $\lim_{N\to\infty} s_N=\sum_0^\infty a_n$ exists, then
$$
\text{if }\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\text{ is finite}\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\neq\pm\infty\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
i.e. Abel summability of the series implies that it cannot diverge. As noted by p4sch, if we even assume that $s_N$ is not converging, it can nevertheless happen that *its Abel summability implies its boundedness*, as the elementary example 
$$
\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}=\{(-1)^n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}
$$ shows. This leads to the following

> **Question**: does Abel summability of the series $\sum_0^N a_n$ always implies the boundedness of the sequence $\{s_N\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of its partial sums, or more precisely does the following implication holds?
>   $$
> \text{if }\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\text{ is finite}\implies -\infty<\liminf_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N a_n\le\limsup_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N a_n<+\infty\label{2}\tag{2}
> $$

**My attempt**. I tried to extend the method of proof used by zwh, since it seemed suited to obtain the sought for result. I started attacking the problem by trying to prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n\neq\infty \implies \limsup_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N a_n<+\infty\label{1a}\tag{1a}
$$
provided $\liminf_{N\to\infty} s_N>-\infty$. Now it is only the right side of \eqref{1a} which holds therefore, for a general positive $M$, there exist an integer $N'$ for which there exists *an infity of partial sums* $s_{n_i}$ (but *not all*) such that 
$$
s_{n_i}\ge M\qquad\forall n_{i}>N'\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
Thus we have
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n &= (1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_nx^n\\
&= (1-x)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N'} s_nx^n + \sum_{n_i\ge N'+1}^\infty s_{n_i}x^{n_i} +\sum_{n_j\ge N'+1}^\infty s_{n_j}x^{n_j}\right)
\end{split}
$$
where the partial sums $\{s_{n_j}\}_{j\in\Bbb N}$ are the ones which *do not* satisfy \eqref{3}. At this point, however, I am not able to find an arbitrary large lower bound for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and obtain the "reductio ad absurdum".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the statement is in general false. Consider
$$f(x):=\sum_{n\geq1}(-1)^{n+1}nx^n=\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$$
$f(x)$ converges to $1/4$ as $x\rightarrow1-$ but partial sums of the series
$\sum_{n\geq1}(-1)^{n+1}n$ oscillate with increasing amplitude: $-1,1,-2,2,...,-n,n,...$

Comment: Thanks: I seems that I missed a very simple counterexample. :D

Comment: That happens... I have not yet found an example in which $-\infty<\liminf_n s_n$ and $\limsup_n s_n=\infty$ though. I don't know whether the same type of example (derivatives of $x\mapsto\frac{1}{1-x}$ and combinations thereof) will provide such example.